# Why does Vim ignore files in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I seem to have a problem with my local Vim configuration but I'm not sure what it is. I need to override some filetype-specific settings. As per multiple tutorials/howtos, I created `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim` with appropriate `setlocal` statements, but it seems not to be read. I checked that `~/.vim/after` is in `runtimepath`.

I worked around this with `autocmd FileType cpp setlocal ...` in `~/.vimrc`, but that is beyond the point. Any advice on how to diagnose/fix this? Or am I just overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check the output of:

```
:filetype
```

You may need to add

```
filetype plugin on
```

to your .vimrc (or at least add 'plugin' to your 'filetype' setting).

Answer (score 11):

A good place to start would be to use the `:scriptnames` command.  Open a C++ file however you normally do and execute

```
:scriptnames
```

This will show you the files that Vim has sourced since it was started.

Comment: That's a useful tip for debugging. I used to run `vim --cmd 'set verbose=2'` in order to see which script files were being sourced.

Comment: Yes, very useful. I learned that, the load-order of after-plugins is not what you would think, see answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20227/20753 about that.